# Display a post of subcategories in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Consider:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts( array('category_name' => 'parent','posts_per_page'=>'3','paged' => $paged));
    if(have_posts()):
        while(have_posts()):
?>

    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="entry"> Sorry, no posts found. Please try the
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">Homepage &rarr;</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code only displays the parent post of the page, but I want to display the pages which are under the parent category: For example: ParentPage -> ChildPage. I need to display the child page...

Comment: Side comment. You don't need to use the opening and closing php tags in each line. You can just make `while(have_posts()): the_post();  endwhile; else:` ...

Comment: Thanks.. but how to get the subcategories from the above query?

Comment: Do you mean "display the posts from the child category"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to query the child of that parent categories, by [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

```
$child_categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent'  => 0
) );
```

replace 0 with the id of your parent category, Now use the array of child category to get the data,
use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead f query_posts

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '2,6,17,38' ) );
```

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer and add is as the best? @BikashGurung

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    $args = array( 'category_name' => 'child_category' );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

    the_content();
    }
/* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
 // no posts found
    }
?>
```

Thank you... This one solved my Problem. :)

Comment: May I ask how will you get the child categories from parent categories?@BikashGurung